# Unable to render block in twig after updating Twig Tweak module

Tags: theming, blocks

I update the [Twig Tweak](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_tweak) module to version 8.x-2.x. After this update I can't render my disabled blocks anymore?

Before I used `{{ drupal_block('myblockname') }}` to render my block in the twig template.

Now I try to use `{{ drupal_entity('block','myblockname', check_access=false) }}`. But I don't see my blocks in the frontend?

Comment: What does 'myblockname' stand for? Is it entity ID or plugin ID? Does this work for you when the block is enabled?

Answer (score 3):

It was a docker sync problem. Now with `{{ drupal_entity('block','myblockname', check_access=false) }}` the blocks are visible.